Android 14 Chrome, Add to Home screen Install, for internal URL path
Is there a way to use Chrome Add to home screen -> install feature to create a home screen 'app' that points to an internal path of a domain ?
For example if I go to a FB group https:://www.facebook.com/groups/somegroup and then go through Add to Home screen -> Install, I get a home screen icon that opens FB home page not the group.
Is there a way through chrome or third party app to achieve this ?

Possibly related/dupe: Chrome and Firefox cannot add specific URL to home screen

@AndrewT. yes please mark it
